# UITableView refresh crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, timer

I have a UITableView that gets JSON data from a Twitter search. I'm using polling to auto-refresh the view.

In my viewDidLoad, I have:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(autoTweets:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and then I have:

```
-(void) autoTweets : (NSTimer *)theTweets
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hatlive%20-%22RT%20%40%22"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    if (connection)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    [[self myTableView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self myTableView]setDataSource:self];
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Doing this refreshes the data every 10 seconds. The problem is, if I scroll on the 10th second when the code is executed, the app just crashes. If I don't scroll, it updates just fine. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you post the delegate implementation as well? Where does it crash? Do you use multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `array` is the data used by the table view's data source, then the problem is that you change the contents of the array at the start of the connection. Then the contents get updated as the connection completes in the background. Meanwhile, as the table is scrolling, it is still trying to access the old contents of the array.

One solution is to setup a temporary array used to deal with the new connection. Don't update the old array with the new array until just before you call `reloadData` on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[self.tableView beginUpdates];` and `[self.tableView endUpdates];` while updating your data. Also you dont have to reset the datasource and delegate all the time. You may even call `[self.tableView reloadData];`.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable touch on the table view right before the refresh, then enable after the data is set.

```
self.myTableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // before refresh
self.myTableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;  // after
```